# PHP Redirection (301) hiding query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect a page using PHP (I think it has to be PHP as opposed to .htaccess as there are a lot of pages involved and the information required to do the redirect is held in a datbase).

The page i'm trying to to a redirect from is already re-written, and looks like:

www.example.com/shop/deptartment/section/product1/

Which re-writes to www.example.com/content.php?dept=department&sect=section&prod=product

However when I use the php `header($url,TRUE,301);` with $url being (For example) www.example.com/shop/deptartment/section/product2/ it re-directs to:

**www.example.com/shop/deptartment/section/product2/?dept=department&sect=section&prod=product**

Wheras all I want is www.example.com/shop/deptartment/section/product2/

I know how to stop this in .htaccess but not php, any ideas ?

Many thanks,

Stuart

p.s. rewrite rules are:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/?$ /content.php?dept=$1&sect=$2&prod=$3 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^shop/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/?$ /content.php?dept=$1&sect=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^shop/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/?$ /content.php?dept=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^shop/ /content.php [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: This is a confusing question... Post your rewrite rules.

Comment: I'll second that, it sounds like your RewriteRules have the [R=301] flag on them, which they shouldn't have if you are attempting to simply alias the address with the 'pretty' URI.

Comment: Sorry if it was confusing, just trying to give as much info as possible. RewriteRules are above.

I have the QSA on there so when google adwords clicks come in a script on the page can track the gclid get variable.

Comment: Edit the question and post that in there. Too jumbled on the comment part to sift through it.

Comment: I don't see how with those RewriteRules you could ever get that long URL. QSA simply appends the query string of the requested URL to the redirected one. The link coming from google should be example.com/shop/department/section/product2/?gclid=blah, which shouldn't cause any problems. It very much sounds like you are messing it up somewhere you aren't showing us. I still don't understand why you are attempting a header redirect anyway?

Comment: @stukerr : do you have other rewrite mechanism (like mod_alias) running? Those might be the culprit.

Comment: Where do you get the value of `$url` from?